# Force particular viewcontroller in landscape in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have 5 navigation controllers in UITabBarController. One of the **Navigationcontroller** in the **UITabBarController** has one 
**Viewcontroller** always Landscape others all Portrait..

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

Above code I put in **NavigationController** subclass.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Above code I put in **Landscape Controller**.

I have Base as UIViewController subclass in that I put this code

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[LanscapeViewController class]])
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

If I present that viewcontroller it works well show that screen only landscape. But if I push the **ViewController** in remains in Portrait.

Answer (score 1):

Have you write below code inside ViewController for Portrait Mode.

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown | UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: @TamilKing, 
Why you checking kindOfClass inside same class? this if ([self isKindOfClass:[LanscapeViewController class]]) condition always true, because you are in same LanscapeViewController class. 

Please return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown in all portrait VC and  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft in all Landscape VC.

Comment: That is subclass of UIViewcontroller all the viewcontroller under the subclass so only I check like this.. So oly.. @Punita

Comment: But you can overwrite super class method by writing method implementation in each sub class of UIViewController.

Comment: I put the your code in other class but not working.. Bt I present it works.. Thanks for your fast response..

Comment: Please right tick to my answer if you got any idea from answer. Thanks

Comment: Actually It works before itself without your code but i need to change while push... Please check my question.. +1 for your response..

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article. 
http://www.klecker.de/photo/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=148&Itemid=213
or 
[Presenting Navigation Controller in Landscape mode is not working ios 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519486/presenting-navigation-controller-in-landscape-mode-is-not-working-ios-6-0)
respectively.

I did do that in a tab bar app, but I did not force the rotation of the direct root viewcontoller of one of the tabs but for one of its subviews. I am not sure if this works with one of a tab bar's view controllers directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIViewController` Category to Check current ViewController,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (Utils)

+(UIViewController*) currentViewController;

@end

#import "UIViewController+Utils.h"

@implementation UIViewController (Utils)

+(UIViewController*) findBestViewController:(UIViewController*)vc {

    if (vc.presentedViewController) {

        // Return presented view controller
        return [UIViewController findBestViewController:vc.presentedViewController];

    } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[UISplitViewController class]]) {

        // Return right hand side
        UISplitViewController* svc = (UISplitViewController*) vc;
        if (svc.viewControllers.count > 0)
            return [UIViewController findBestViewController:svc.viewControllers.lastObject];
        else
            return vc;

    } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

        // Return top view
        UINavigationController* svc = (UINavigationController*) vc;
        if (svc.viewControllers.count > 0)
            return [UIViewController findBestViewController:svc.topViewController];
        else
            return vc;

    } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {

        // Return visible view
        UITabBarController* svc = (UITabBarController*) vc;
        if (svc.viewControllers.count > 0)
            return [UIViewController findBestViewController:svc.selectedViewController];
        else
            return vc;

    } else {

        // Unknown view controller type, return last child view controller
        return vc;

    }

}

+(UIViewController*) currentViewController {

    // Find best view controller
    UIViewController* viewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    return [UIViewController findBestViewController:viewController];

}

@end
```

In `Appdelegate.m` import Above UIViewcontroller Category, Import ViewController which you want to show in Landscape and implement orientation method as

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([[UIViewController currentViewController] isKindOfClass:[YourLandScapeViewController class]]) {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; //Orientation for LandScapeViewcontroller

    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; // rest All ViewController
}
```